# How to prevent keil v5.36 armclang optimizing some statements in c/c++?

Tags: c++, arm, stm32, compiler-optimization

I have code that compares one string to another, but with optimizer(-Oz image size + LTO) turned on, I recieve some problems. I've tried volatile parameters but me variables are still optimized.

```cpp
bool INA239::getBusStatus() { 
volatile uint8_t ManfId[3] = "TI";
volatile uint8_t* data = readReg(INA239_REG_MANUFACTURER_ID);
volatile bool result = !memcmp((uint8_t*)data, (uint8_t*)ManfId, 2);
return result;
}
```

`readReg()` function reads data from SPI using DMA and as I see on my SPI buffer, it performs OK.

```cpp
uint8_t* INA239::readReg(uint8_t RegNo) {
    SPITxBuffer[0] = (RegNo << 2) | 0x01;
    SPITxBuffer[1] = 0x00;
    SPITxBuffer[2] = 0x00;
    while(!DSPI->ModeChange(GPort, GPin, INA239_CPOL, INA239_CPHA));
    while(!DSPI->TXRX(SPITxBuffer, SPIRxBuffer, INA239_SPIBUFFERSIZE + (RegNo == INA239_REG_POWER)));
    while(DSPI->Maintain);
    return &SPIRxBuffer[1];
}
```

it sends data and waits for HAL_SPI_TxRxCpltCallback

I've found strange solution that somewhat work:

1. Add `HAL_Delay(1)` after

```cpp
volatile uint8_t* data = readReg(INA239_REG_MANUFACTURER_ID);
```

But I have no need to do any of this if optimizer flag is `-O0`

It seems like optimized code perform strange with DMA.

I thought that optimizer ignores empty body while loop and yes:

```
    57:         while(!DSPI->TXRX(SPITxBuffer, SPIRxBuffer, INA239_SPIBUFFERSIZE + (RegNo == INA239_REG_POWER))); 
    58:         while(DSPI->Maintain); 
0x08003EFA 4631      MOV      r1,r6
0x08003EFC 4622      MOV      r2,r4
0x08003EFE 462B      MOV      r3,r5
0x08003F00 F7FDFD8B  BL.W     0x08001A1A OUTLINED_FUNCTION_9
0x08003F04 2800      CMP      r0,#0x00
0x08003F06 D0F8      BEQ      0x08003EFA
```

this should act OK, I thought, as there is `BEQ      0x08003EFA`, but no, it is ignored
[image]

As a solution I made `Maintain` a `volatile bool` and after that that assembler code is:

```
    58:         while(DSPI->Maintain); 
0x08003F86 F8901021  LDRB     r1,[r0,#0x21]
0x08003F8A 2900      CMP      r1,#0x00
0x08003F8C D1FB      BNE      0x08003F86
```

[image]

But I want all my INA239 functions to be not optimized.
So is there any way to make armclang v6 to not optimize block of code?

I've tried:

1)

```cpp
#pragma push

#pragma O0

void function2(void)
{

}

#pragma pop
```

but compiler says that this is arm v5 compiler options and will not work on v6

(-Warmcc-pragma-optimization)

2)

```cpp
void __attribute__((optimize("O0")))
```

but get unkown attribute warning

3)

```cpp
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")

your code

#pragma GCC pop_options
```

no messages, but doesn't work
4)

```cpp
#pragma push_options
#pragma optimize ("O0")

your code

#pragma pop_options
```

no messages, but doesn't work

Comment: Any variable that can be changed in an ISR should probably be volatile. So that is the correct solution, not turning off optimisation.

Comment: Note that it's pretty arbitrary what an "optimization" exactly is. You can "optimize away" the empty statement `;`, you can "optimize away" the trivial loop `while(true) { ; }`, you can optimize away `while(false) { ; }` - all reasonable things to do at `-O0`. `volatile` reads on the other hand are explicitly observable behavior and excluded from optimization at _any_ level.

Comment: What are you hoping `volatile bool result = !memcmp` / `return result` will do?  You're just forcing the compiler to store/reload the bool after it generates it, because `result` is `volatile`.  It has no effect on the `memcmp` that produces the result you're assigning, if that's what you were trying to do.  And you're casting away `volatile` from `ManfId` (which makes sense, it's a fixed constant, you don't need the compiler to assume it might have changed.  It shouldn't be `volatile` in the first place).

Comment: `memcmp` isn't safely usable on an object that's asynchronously modified because its operands aren't `volatile *`.  In this case you might use `typedef uint16_t unaligned_aliasing_u16 __attribute__((aligned(1), may_alias))` and use `volatile unaligned_aliasing_u16 *data` to load 2 bytes from anything as a volatile operation, then compare it normally.

Comment: These are not asynchronously changing. I just needed to look in debug what are the values of these variables. My fault, at first it was just one string return of `!memcmp(readReg(...), "TI")`